# Normalize OSM geometry to 1x1 coordinate system

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, geometry-conversion, web-mercator

I'm extracting a couple of geometries with overpass turbo and need to "normalize" their shape from lat-lon to [[0-1][0-1]] coordinates.

The first thing I've tried is probably pretty wrong: get highest & smallest lat-lon values in the geometry and remap them to 0-1. This is the JS code:

```
function (geometry) {
    let biggestLat = geometry[0][0];
    let biggestLong = geometry[0][1];

    for (let i = 0; i < geometry.length; i++) {
        if (biggestLat < geometry[i][0]) {
            biggestLat = geometry[i][0];
        }

        if (biggestLong < geometry[i][1]) {
            biggestLong = geometry[i][1];
        }
    }

    let smallestLat = geometry[0][0];
    let smallestLong = geometry[0][1];

    for (let i = 0; i < geometry.length; i++) {
        if (smallestLat > geometry[i][0]) {
            smallestLat = geometry[i][0];
        }

        if (smallestLong > geometry[i][1]) {
            smallestLong = geometry[i][1];
        }
    }

    let coordinatesArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < geometry.length; i++) {

        let lat = this.map_range(geometry[i][0], smallestLat, biggestLat, 0, 1);
        let lon = this.map_range(geometry[i][1], smallestLong, biggestLong, 0, 1);
        coordinatesArray.push([lat, lon]);

    }

    return coordinatesArray
}
```

And the result is obviously pretty off:

[image: comparison]

I've been reading about the different projection methods and that I need to decide for one, but I don't really understand which I should use in this case. Mercator seems to be wrong?

To summarize my aim: I want to scale any Geometry i get from osm to the same size in a x,y coordinate system. Can anyone explain me how to do it correctly or what framework to use to do the calculation? I've been using `turf.js` in other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually, what I missed, is to reverse the mercator projection. Then everything was fine:

```
function mercator (longitude, latitude) {
  var radius = 6378137;
  var max = 85.0511287798;
  var radians = Math.PI / 180;
  var point = {};

  point.x = radius * longitude * radians;
  point.y = Math.max(Math.min(max, latitude), -max) * radians;
  point.y = radius * Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + (point.y / 2)));

  return point;
}
```

I got it from http://mikefowler.me/journal/2014/06/10/drawing-geojson-in-a-canvas

I also messed up the long lat order + taking the relation of the bounding box of the shape into account:

```
function normalizeGeometry(geometry) {
    let biggestLong = geometry[0][0];
    let biggestLat = geometry[0][1];

    for (let i = 0; i < geometry.length; i++) {
        if (biggestLong < geometry[i][0]) {
            biggestLong = geometry[i][0];
        }
        if (biggestLat < geometry[i][1]) {
            biggestLat = geometry[i][1];
        }
    }

    let smallestLong = geometry[0][0];
    let smallestLat = geometry[0][1];

    for (let i = 0; i < geometry.length; i++) {
        if (smallestLat > geometry[i][1]) {
            smallestLat = geometry[i][1];
        }

        if (smallestLong > geometry[i][0]) {
            smallestLong = geometry[i][0];
        }
    }

    // calculate Ratio
    let width = biggestLong - smallestLong;
    let height = biggestLat - smallestLat;
    let ratio;

    let smallestLatRemap = 0;
    let biggestLatRemap = 1;
    let smallestLonRemap = 0;
    let biggestLonRemap = 1;

    if (width > height) { // landscape
        ratio = height / width;
        let shift = 1 - ratio;
        smallestLatRemap += shift / 2;
        biggestLatRemap -= shift / 2;
    } else if (width < height) { // portrait
        ratio = width / height;
        let shift = 1 - ratio;
        smallestLonRemap += shift / 2;
        biggestLonRemap -= shift / 2;
    } else { // square ratio
    }

    let coordinatesArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < geometry.length; i++) {
        let lon = this.map_range(geometry[i][0], smallestLong, biggestLong, smallestLonRemap, biggestLonRemap);
        let lat = this.map_range(geometry[i][1], smallestLat, biggestLat, biggestLatRemap, smallestLatRemap);
        coordinatesArray.push([lon, lat]);
    }

    return coordinatesArray
}
```